# Magento : catalog_product_save_before with mass action

Tags: magento, events, magento-1.7, product

I've made a new mass action to refresh some attributes on selected products based on a algorithm.

I need to trigger "catalog_product_save_before" as if I was saving my product trough the standard admin product creation/edition.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Code sample :

```
<catalog_product_save_before>
    <observers>
        <SaponeWebConcept_AttributeToCategories>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>attributetocategories/observer</class>
            <method>beforeSave</method>
        </SaponeWebConcept_AttributeToCategories>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_save_before>
```

Where it works (standard product creation/edition)

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$product = $event->getProduct();
//And then I edit my product
```

Where it doesn't : I get my `$productID`, load it, then save, but the above code isn't triggered.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
//Some verifications
$product->save();
```

`$productID` is set in a foreach where I got all selected products ID of the product grid.

Answer (score 2):

Mass action doesn't fire catalog_product_save_before event.
use catalog_product_attribute_update_before event instead and then do nested product load/save

I just did it in my magento 1.6.2 code and it worked fine.
loop through product ids{
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
 ... some code ...
 $product->save();
}

be sure to set all important changes to a product before nested $product->save() invocation so that this event handler has all product attributes in correct state

Comment: Although I worry a bit about the impact on the serverload by iterating through an array with ID's, performing numerous `load/save()`-actions on the fly, I must say that this answer does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked it up in code, but I'm guessing your mass action is not firing a save at all. As far as I can remember a mass action save jumps into the same save model method as the regular save does.

Comment: I forgot something important.
I load a product trough it's ID, ofc, and save it with
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
$product->save(); 

but it doesn't trig the event.

Comment: show me your observer declaration xml `<event>...` and the path to the actual observer class and maybe the class itself

Comment: It works if I use the standard product creator. Anyway, 1st post edited.

Comment: Maybe I need to call another function than save ?

Comment: No catalog_product_save_before dispatches every time before a product is saved via the orm regular save method  `$product->save()`

Try to dispatch the event for yourself before saving, just for testing.

`Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_controller_product_view', array('product'=>$product))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `setDataChanges()` method on the product object to indicate something was/will be changed.

Here is a simple example from my code:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->setDataChanges(true)->save();
```

This looks a bit odd on its own, but I have an observer, which will do some magic on product save.

If you have a look at `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::save()` you can see it checks if the product needs to be saved:

```
if (!$this->_hasModelChanged()) {
    return $this;
}
```

Therefore if you don't make any changes to the product or don't tell it that there are data changes, then it assumes there is nothing to save and the `catalog_product_save_before` won't be triggered.